# Core TeX "Hello, world!"

Tags: tex-core

As an experiment, I wish to write a manuscript in core TeX, which typesets the text "Hello, world!", and compile it without any format.

If I was using the Plain TeX format, this program would be

```
Hello, world!
\bye
```

So to make this program independent of the format, I've copied all the missing definitions from plain.tex, and arrived at the following:

```
\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2
\catcode`@=11
\mathchardef\@MM=20000
\def\supereject{\par\penalty-\@MM}
\catcode`@=12
\outer\def\bye{\par\vfill\supereject\end}
Hello, world!
\bye
```

When I compile this manuscript with `tex -ini`, the compilation proceeds successfully, and a dvi file is created. However, the dvi is empty. Why?

Comment: Nice hobby :) -- you seem to try to learn LaTeX from the scratch.

Comment: You haven't specified any fonts.

Comment: Don't you mean `tex -ini` rather than `tex -init`? You can run `dvitype` on the DVI to see what it contains; the DVI format is actually pretty cool.

Comment: try `\hsize=10cm
\vsize=10cm
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil 
%\lineskip=1pt
%\baselineskip=12pt
%\lineskiplimit=0pt
\font\myfont=cmr10 \myfont
Hello world
\end`

Comment: I know I've mentioned this before, but if you are looking for understanding at this level you need to read _The TeXbook_ several times, work through the code of `plain.tex`, _etc._

Comment: @JosephWright: Feel free to remove my edit. While you're at it, delete  percusse's answer, since, to follow your argument, the question wasn't "How to write "Hello, world!" directly in PDF."

Comment: Your habit of adding wrong `%` characters will bite you, some day. ;-) None of the ones you use in the first block of code is necessary and five of them are wrong.

Comment: @JosephWright Too late, I guess :-). But ShreevatsaR's answer is much better than I would have written. Even if it no longer makes sense as an answer to the edited question. There isn't now still a question at all, as far as I can tell. (And I don't see that this has anything to do with the answers posted - the site has agreed answers to related questions can be posted, but not that questions shouldn't be questions.)

Comment: @egreg: Which ones are wrong, and why?

Comment: Lines 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 had a wrong `%` resulting in no space after a constant; lines 5,7 and 8 had redundant ones.

Comment: See http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113gregorio.pdf for some examples of shooting one's own foot.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296880/how-to-typeset-in-initex

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Firstly, let's start with a simpler plain TeX file that does not use the `\bye` macro:

```
Hello, world!
\end
```

This already works fine when run with `tex` (produces a DVI file containing “Hello, world!”), and (as `\end` is a TeX primitive and not something defined in `plain.tex`) can be run with `tex -ini` without (visible) errors, but producing a “blank” DVI file.

To see what's going on, we'd like to turn on tracing, maybe [`\tracingall`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60491/latex-tracing-commands-list) if we don't know what sort of tracing we'd like. This `\tracingall` is defined in `plain.tex`, and copying the relevant parts from `plain.tex` exactly as you did, gives:

```
\catcode`\{=1%
\catcode`\}=2%

\catcode`@=11%
\chardef\@ne=1
\chardef\tw@=2
\def\loggingall{\tracingcommands\tw@\tracingstats\tw@
  \tracingpages\@ne\tracingoutput\@ne\tracinglostchars\@ne
  \tracingmacros\tw@\tracingparagraphs\@ne\tracingrestores\@ne
  % \showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen}
  \showboxbreadth100\showboxdepth100}
\def\tracingall{\tracingonline\@ne\loggingall}
\catcode`@=12%

\tracingall

Hello, world!
\end
```

(I cheated a bit: the commented out line above with `\showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen` is the original; I just used `\showboxbreadth100\showboxdepth100` to avoid having to pull in definitions of `\maxdimen` which needs `\newdimen` which needs `\alloc@` etc.) Anyway, with this it's easier to see the issue in the output: lines like

```
{the letter H}
{horizontal mode: the letter H}
Missing character: There is no H in font nullfont!
{the letter e}
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
```

and so on. Actually you can get this output even with a smaller `.tex` file:

```
\tracingonline=1
\tracingcommands=2
\tracinglostchars=1
Hello, world!
\end
```

Anyway, now that you know that the issue is fonts, you can copy over the relevant bits from `plain.tex` (again I've replaced a few lines from `plain.tex` (commented out) with simpler equivalents, to avoid copying a whole lot):

```
\catcode`\{=1 % left brace is begin-group character
\catcode`\}=2 % right brace is end-group character

\font\tenrm=cmr10 % roman text

% \def\rm{\fam\z@\tenrm}
\def\rm{\fam0\tenrm}
% \normalbaselines\rm % select roman font
\rm % select roman font

Hello, world!
\end
```

Running this with `tex -ini` typesets the characters in the output, but causes an interesting issue: the resulting dvi file has two pages, one containing “Hello,” and one containing “world!”

But the original issue is resolved, so I'll leave it to you to figure out this mystery. :-)

---

**Edit**: For completeness here is a minimal `.tex` file that when run with `tex -ini` produces an identical `.dvi` file (identical except for the timestamp comment of course) as a `.tex` file containing `Hello, world!\bye` does when run with `tex`:

```
\catcode`\{=1 % left brace is begin-group character
\catcode`\}=2 % right brace is end-group character

\hsize=6.5in
\vsize=8.9in
\parindent=20pt

\topskip=10pt
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil

\font\tenrm=cmr10 % roman text

\def\line{\hbox to\hsize}

\countdef\pageno=0 \pageno=1 % first page is number 1

\output{\plainoutput}
\def\plainoutput{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}}
\def\pagebody{\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth\maxdepth \pagecontents}}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to0pt{\vskip-22.5pt \line{\vbox to8.5pt{}\hfil}\vss}}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24pt\lineskiplimit0pt\line{\hss\tenrm\number\pageno\hss}}
\def\pagecontents{\unvbox255}

\tenrm % select roman font
Hello, world!
\end
```

Every line (before the last two) is either from `plain.tex` or a simplified version of one, and removing any line makes the DVI output no longer identical. (Of course to make it minimal I've removed a lot that is useful such as the instruction in `\plainoutput` that advances the page number, so this will not work when you have more than one paragraph or even more than one line, let alone more than one page.)

Comment: Thanks. If you know why, can you please spell out the reason the pdf is 2 pages? There are enough mysteries out there for me to figure out on my own...

Comment: @EvanAad You've not set `\hsize`, so it's 0pt and TeX breaks into pages at every piece of whitespace. You probably want to set that and `\parfillskip` too.

Comment: @EvanAad I've gone further and produced a minimal `.tex` file for running with `tex -ini`, that produces the same output (including the positions on the page, and the page number at the bottom) as the hello-world plain-TeX file.

Answer (score 24):

Skip TeX, write a PDF directly, it's a compiler-free solution. (just compiled the examples that I've learned from [this blog](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/?s=%22Make+your+own+PDF+file%22)). Paste it in a text editor and save it as a PDF file.

```
%PDF-1.1
%¥±ë

1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [3 0 R]
     /Count 1
     /MediaBox [0 0 100 15]
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  <<  /Type /Page
      /Parent 2 0 R
      /Resources
       << /Font
           << /F1
               << /Type /Font
                  /Subtype /Type1
                  /BaseFont /Times-Roman
               >>
           >>
       >>
      /Contents 4 0 R
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj
  << /Length 55 >>
stream
  BT
    /F1 18 Tf
    0 0 Td
    (Hello World) Tj
  ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000018 00000 n 
0000000077 00000 n 
0000000178 00000 n 
0000000457 00000 n 
trailer
  <<  /Root 1 0 R
      /Size 5
  >>
startxref
565
%%EOF
```

[image]

Comment: Whats's the `%¥±ë` for?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner They are the high bit chars. You need at least 4 of them for the header.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Has this to do with font encoding?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Not really. It's the bizarre PDF specification *If a PDF file contains binary data, as most do (see 7.2, "Lexical Conventions"), the header line shall be immediately followed by a comment line containing at least four binary characters—that is, characters whose codes are 128 or greater. This ensures proper behaviour of file transfer applications that inspect data near the beginning of a file to determine whether to treat the file’s contents as text or as binary.*

Comment: I've upvoted it because writing PDFs by hand is really cool. :-)

Comment: This PDF does not contain binary data, and there are only three high-bit chars in that line.

Comment: It might take a while to typeset *War and peace*, but it will be probably done before my thesis... 

Comment: “write a PDF directly” Who doesn't, nowadays. :P Pretty nice answer, actually!

Comment: @Mass They are unicode chars so each of them are actually 2 chars --> 6 chars

Comment: This does not load in Vivaldi, my browser... (built on chromium), nor microsoft edge

Comment: @MCMastery You have to open in a PDF viewer

Answer (score 13):

Here's a minimal core TeX manuscript that typesets "Hello, world!".

```
\font\myfont=cmr10\myfont
    % When the font is unspecified, it defaults to the nullfont,
    % in which glyphs have no visual representation.
    % Without this line the dvi page will appear empty.
%
\hsize=10cm
    % When \hsize is unspecified, it defaults to 0pt,
    % which causes TeX to break page at every whitespace.
    % Without this line the words will be placed on separate pages.
%
\parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
    % When \parfillskip is unspecified,
    % the whitepasce between words will stretch
    % to fill up as much line space as possible
    % while keeping all words on a single line.
    % The total line width is given by \hsize.
    % Without this line the two words will be positioned
    % at the opposite sides of a line that is 10cm wide.
%
Hello, world!
\end
```

* This answer is based on the contributions of [cfr's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world/388360?noredirect=1#comment963111_388352), [touhami's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world/388360?noredirect=1#comment963125_388352), [ShreevatsaR's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388360/21685), and [Joseph Wright's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world/388360?noredirect=1#comment963178_388360).

Comment: what about `\catcode`\{=1
\catcode`\}=2
\font\myfont=cmr10 \myfont

\hbox{Hello world}
\end`

Comment: try to type the catcode correctly

Comment: @touhami: Yes, very nice, but it should be `\catcode\``, no? I don't know why you never wrote an answer.