# Documents written in TeX (no LaTeX, no Plain TeX)

Tags: tex-core

LaTeX and Plain TeX are formats for TeX and they ease creating document. But can we create documents using only TeX? I couldn't find any pure TeX sample.

Comment: See also [*Core TeX "Hello, world!"*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388352/48)

Answer (score 9):

You can write *simple* documents using only TeX primitives:

```
\font\rm=ptmr7t
\font\bf=ptmb7t
\font\sl=ptmro7t
\rm
\hrule
\vskip 1in
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\bf A SHORT STORY\hss}
\vskip 6pt
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\sl by A. U. Thor\hss}
\vskip .5cm
Once upon a time, in a distant
  galaxy called \accent "7F O\accent "7F o\accent 24 c,
there lived a computer
named R.\penalty10000\ J. Drofnats.

Mr.\penalty10000\ Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
he preferred to be called---%
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.
\vskip 1in
\hrule
\vfill\penalty-10000
\end
```

[image]

It's however obvious that macros are essential, not only for making our lives better.

Using some canned set of macros helps in communication.

---

If you want *no format*, then you need to do more initializations, running the file with `pdftex -ini -output-format=pdf`

```
\catcode`\{=1 % left brace is begin-group character
\catcode`\}=2 % right brace is end-group character
\catcode`\$=3 % dollar sign is math shift
\catcode`\&=4 % ampersand is alignment tab
\catcode`\#=6 % hash mark is macro parameter character
\catcode`\^=7 \catcode`\^^K=7 % circumflex and uparrow are for superscripts
\catcode`\_=8 \catcode`\^^A=8 % underline and downarrow are for subscripts
\catcode`\^^I=10 % ascii tab is a blank space
\chardef\active=13 \catcode`\~=\active % tilde is active
\catcode`\^^L=\active \outer\def^^L{\par} % ascii form-feed is "\outer\par"

\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in
\hsize=6.5in
\vsize=8.9in
\baselineskip=12pt

\font\rm=ptmr7t
\font\bf=ptmb7t
\font\sl=ptmro7t
\rm
\hrule
\vskip 1in
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\bf A SHORT STORY\hss}
\vskip 6pt
\hbox to \hsize{\hss\sl by A. U. Thor\hss}
\vskip .5cm
Once upon a time, in a distant
  galaxy called \accent "7F O\accent "7F o\accent 24 c,
there lived a computer
named R.\penalty10000\ J. Drofnats.

Mr.\penalty10000\ Drofnats---or ``R. J.,'' as
he preferred to be called---%
was happiest when he was at work
typesetting beautiful documents.
\vskip 1in
\hrule
\vfill\penalty-10000
\end
```

Comment: Is `\break` a TeX primitive?

Comment: @Johnwebner Oh, I missed that!

Comment: +1. On the other hand this also shows that macros are *not* essential, if one is not directly typing the `.tex` file but generating it from text written in some other format; i.e. if one is using TeX as just the typesetting tool and not as the complete user interface.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Some stuff would be very tricky without, for example anything which needs to know which page material appears on

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Try implementing a recursive action without macros.

Comment: @egreg I used the code above with `\vfill\break` and pdfTeX generated a PDF file. Is `\break` a TeX macro or a Plain TeX macro?

Comment: @Johnwebner It's the same `\penalty-10000` in both plain TeX and LaTeX (but it is not mentioned in the LaTeX manual and only used internally, because `\linebreak` or `\pagebreak` are preferred).

Comment: @egreg Does it mean pdfTeX loads plain TeX by default? If not why does pdfTeX understand it?

Comment: @Johnwebner Yes, that's right: plain TeX is assumed. You could run `pdftex -ini`, but then some further initialization has to be added.

Comment: @JosephWright Right, it's not always possible to completely generate a `.tex` file offline, for some tasks. But even there IMO there are better ways of interacting with the TeX state than text-substitution macros. E.g. with LuaTeX one has hooks; or even otherwise one could conceive of ways of say pausing and restarting TeX after dumping relevant info. (I did do a [fun project](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401604/book-on-a-single-poster-page) last year which did exactly need know which page material appears on… It was tricky sure, but macros wouldn't have made it less tricky AFAICT.)