# pdftex with error 3.1415 ... cannot work after update with windows 10 and 11

Tags: pdftex, pdf, windows, miktex-update

[image]

PDFTEX cannot work, but PDFLATEX is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\documentclass` is a LaTeX command, it is not a TeX command.

Comment: nobody meets the same issue?

Comment: As Heiko pointed out: what you are using is **La**TeX code. It cannot be compiled with pure TeX. See this thread for more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457033/documents-written-in-tex-no-latex-no-plain-tex

Comment: Welcome :) // The reason, why pdftex can't work, has already been given. Historically Tex came first, and was made more user friendly through a series of macros, which became Latex. Which implies that a Tex-setting can't deal with Latex-code.

Comment: Thanks to your answers, but if I would like to make the PDFTEX works, how should I can this line?

Comment: you need a different document if you want to use pdftex:  `hello world! \bye`.