# Will LaTeX compile Plain TeX?

Tags: miktex, tex-core, plain-tex

I'm really new to TeX and I'm trying to learn how the different levels of TeX relate to each other. As far as I understand LaTeX is a set of macros for Plain TeX with the purpose of making life easier, in that sense I wonder whether LaTeX will compile Plain Tex, since LaTeX is just a set of macros.

For instance, I've tried the very basic `\bye` command of Plain TeX with a LaTeX compiler and it didn't work, I would love to learn the logic behind it.

Edit:
I've figured that Plain TeX is also a set of macros, I thought that it was the pure TeX (which turned out to be called "Virgin TeX"), that explains why `\bye` won't be compiled in LaTeX but when I try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world) in LaTeX it still won't be compiled.

Comment: plain tex and latex share no code, although both are written in tex, so you would not expect any plain tex defined commands to work in latex. Some latex commands have the same names as commands defined in plain tex and some of those (not many) have the same definition.

Comment: your edited last paragraph is the answer here. `\bye` is defined in plain tex, not a tex primitive so it is not defined in latex.

Comment: Think to old English (plain TeX) and middle English (LaTeX): the two languages share much of the grammar and part of the lexicon; but a hypothetical OE speaker cannot understand ME, whereas a ME speaker can understand a lot of OE (not everything).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world This doesn't work though, at least for me, I get "\begin{document} missing". Isn't this supposed to be compiled?

Comment: No why would you expect it to work? latex is set up to require `\begin{document}` before typesetting any paragraphs, so you get the error that you state.

Comment: you could add `\everypar{}` to get rid of that error then you would get an error from `\end`  as you will be using the latex definition of `\end` which will be looking for an argument as in `\end{table}` and not finding one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I expected it to work thinking that LaTeX isn't capable of inhibiting the usage of primitive TeX commands. I know that LaTeX is a different format and we should be playing by its rules but I'm just trying to understand the reasoning behind why it doesn't work like that.

Comment: oh latex inhibits the usage of lots of tex primitives, `\end` for example.  it also doesn't define most of the commands that are in plain tex eg anything to do with page breaking or figure insertion `\topinsert` and friends is not defined at all, so to get a plain tex document to work with latex you have to first undefine a lot of latex, then essentially input plain.tex before running your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thanks, I think I now understand